# Working with elements of a matrix as it was names of other matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix in which I have saved names of other matrices or vectors.

Let's say something like this:

```
        col1   col2
row1    matA   matB
row2    matC   matD
```

Where matA and matB =

```
matA:          col1        matB:           col1
       row1     119                row1     105
       row2      80                row2      99
       row3      95                row3      70
```

I will use a cycle to go through all the rows of the first matrix.

What I need is to calculate average of the first row of matA and matB and save it using `matA = rbind(-calculated_average-,matA)`, same for matB. So the result should be:

```
matA:          col1        matB:           col1
       row1     112                row1     112
       row2     119                row2     105
       row3      80                row3      99
       row4      95                row4      70
```

Then the cycle will move on to 2nd row and calculate the same for matC and matD etc.

If matB wouldn't be defined, I would need to create it and set starting value to 101. The result then would be:

```
matA:          col1        matB:           col1
       row1     110                row1     110
       row2     119                row2     101
       row3      80                
       row4      95
```

The key to my problem is a function which will allow me to work with elements of a matrix as it was names of other matrices.

Comment: When you say the matrix is not defined you mean the variable matB is not present in R? Or that the matrix empty?

Comment: The matrix does not exist in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

As you mentioned yourself key to your problem is a function that will allow to get objects that are saved in memory using their names. The name of the function is `get`. Another function you also need to consider is `ls()` to check what are the variables stored in your memory and `assign` to assign variable using its name as a string. I assume that if the matrix is not defined it is not present in the memory.

I wrote a piece of code that could potentially solve your problem, it is certainly not the most elegant solution but it can serve you as a starting point.

Suppose `dt` is the name of your initial matrix.

```
for i in 1:nrow(dt){
  #check whether at least one matrix is defined
  if(dt[i,1] %in% ls() || dt[i,2] %in% ls()){
    #check whether first matrix is defined
    if(dt[i,1] %in% ls()){
      mat1 = get(dt[i,1])
    #if not define it
    }else{
      mat1 = matrix(101, c(1,1))
    }
    #do the same for the second matrix
    if(dt[i,2] %in% ls(){
      mat2 = get(dt[i,2])
    }else{
      mat2 = matrix(101, c(1,1))
    }
    #calculate averages and reassign
    assign(dt[i,1], rbind(mean(c(mat1[1,1],mat2[1,1])), mat1))
    assign(dt[i,2], rbind(mean(c(mat1[1,1],mat2[1,1])), mat2))
  }
}
```